# Disable https redirects inside a wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

The problem: I've got some iot devices which can't follow redirects. They need to access a directory inside a wordpress site to get a bin file. Apache (i guess using the default wordpress htaccess) is redirecting http to https, and the devices end up receiving the 301 page instead of the bin file.

The solution(?): have and htaccess file in the directory with the bin file which disables any redirects. Assured the htaccess is in effect using 'Deny from all'. Then tried to 'RewriteEngine Off' but the redirects are still there. I'm using curl and wget to test, so there is no browser caching. Any insight on how to solve this is very welcome :)

Comment: Step 1: Stop guessing, and _verify_ how the redirect is actually implemented. (This is not part of a _default_ WP .htaccess setup to begin with.)

Comment: Isn't the local (inside the directory) .htaccess  the one prioritized? In that case, I don't see why there would be a need for tracking down which apache directive implements it. If it's not the case, do you have a proposal on how to track it down?

Comment: Processing of the request would need to make it so far that it actually looks inside the folder to see that .htaccess, but depending on where the redirect is implemented, that might not be the case.